How can Windows update affect branch prediction on CPUs?
There was recently news/benchmarks showing that Ryzen processors (Ryzen 4 and 5) benefit in games from the Windows update. AMD in their blog wrote this is because of branch-prediction changes to Windows:

For “Zen 5” users, here is our recommendation for how to unlock the best performance. Optimized AMD-specific branch prediction code will be available in Windows 11, version 24H2

Now my (maybe wrong?) understanding of branch-prediction in CPUs is that it is not controllable by OS, and any code changes that can occur with regard to branch prediction are updates to CPU microcode.
One way this makes sense is if Windows will learn to dispatch to the different codegen based on CPU (so same source code of Windows compiled with different cost models during optimization stage of compiler codegen) because for example Ryzen 4/5 have such good branch prediction that generation of slower branch free code that worked better on CPUs with worse branch prediction is now suboptimal.
Second option is that maybe due to some HW attacks no longer possible on the new Ryzen CPUs compiler can be made to not generate safe, but slower code.
But this is all speculation, do we know definitive reason for observed speedup?

They are not reprogramming the BPU, they are adapting their code to the new BPU. The Zen 5 BPU is 2-ahead and so it's very different from Zen4. Also now Zen5 has a dual IQ and decode path. It's nothing new that some architecture perform better with code with a specific form than other, but it's still interesting to know exactly what changed and how.

AMD has an (optimization manual for Zen 5](https://www.amd.com/content/dam/amd/en/documents/processor-tech-docs/software-optimization-guides/58455.zip), chapter 2.8.1.2 gives some hint on the conditions for the 2A-BPU to work optimally (e.g. two branches on the same cache line or the second one in the same cache line as the target of the first, the two branches not too far away since the second target address is actually a 5-bit offset from the first). So Windows has room for restructuring its code to better suite this new BPU.
